# DateTime.ToString formats

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0

I am getting issue on single line code ;(

```
TBCurrent.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Current).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

This triggers on timer tick. I've tried already following formats:

```
"HH\:mm\:ss"
"HH':'mm':'ss"
"HH\":\"mm\":\"ss"
```

It works if I put just "mm" or "ss", but not even "HH mm ss".

Did you face such error before? Or this is .NET version (4.0) related?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: "I am getting issue" doesn't tell us *anything* about what you're seeing. What's the error? (As Jeppe states, you're formatting a TimeSpan, not a DateTime, to start with...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Point for him, and Steve. I was sure that DateTime and TimeSpan formats are the same.

Comment: You can also use `(DateTime.Now - Current).ToString( ... )` if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [`TimeSpan` formatting (see link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx), not `DateTime`. Try `"hh':'mm':'ss"`.

It is a usual mistake to think `TimeSpan` formatting is the same as `DateTime` formatting. Before .NET 4.0, you could not format `TimeSpan`.

For `DateTime` there are two ways to write times of day, `20:50` or `8:50 PM`. There `"H"` gives `20`, and `"h"` gives `8`. With `TimeSpan`, that difference is absent and you must always use lowercase `h`.

Answer (score 1):

This format seems to get the output that you want

```
TBCurrent.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Current).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

You need to put the backslashes before the colons because the Subtract method returns a TimeSpan not a DateTime and a TimeSpan has different rules for [Custom Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx). And do not forget the @ verbatim to escape the backslashes